# Angular needing me to set polyfills because of Webpack 5

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, polyfills

So, I was coding, and I ran `ng serve`. It gave me this error about polyfills:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

I looked it up, and none of the fixes helped me. I tried configuring a webpack.config.js, adding a module to Angular polyfilling it, changing the builder (which gave me a ton of security risks in npm) and none of them worked. Oh, and `ng build` also didn't work.

Is there anything else I can do?

**EDIT:** Here's the verbose output. It's very long, so I put it in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/2SKHCJGB).

Comment: Did this happen after installing a specific library inside package.json?

Comment: @Don no, it didn't

Comment: Looks like your app uses some module from NodeJS. You are using `pg` according to the error. It's a Node module. Not for web apps

Comment: @Sergey thanks, i figured it out and forgot about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

It was about some faulty node modules; the `pg` and `node-postgres` modules.